# Search table for each array value

Tags: php, mysql

Please I want to know if its possible to search a database table with an array for example:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE //the possible search for each of the array value// (!in_array(table_colomn, $array)");
```

Is there a possible way to do this or do I have to run a for each function like so:

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    //run table query search for each array value
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator in MySQL.

Comment: yes... so should I run the query like this: `WHERE table_colomn IN '".$array."'`?

Comment: Close, but not quite.  You need to convert the array into a string and build a proper MySQL query.

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE Ouch, that won't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way to do it.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `column` IN ('".implode("', '", $array)."');";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: I fixed your quotes for you :)

Comment: lol... I forgot I don't want to get results from the array values so i guess my code will look like this `WHERE column !IN ('".implode("', '", $array)."'` right?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE use `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT IN ('".implode("', '", $array)."');"`